# trouble deleting object from a array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object, xajax

say i have 3 items in my shopping cart, i want to remove lets say 2 of the 3 items, after the first item removed just fine, the other items will not be removed.
after some testing i saw that before the deletion of the product the data was a array, and after deleting the product, the array transformed into a object.

for example:
`Basket {Klant: Object, Orderlines: Array[0]}`

after adding some items: `Basket {Klant: Object, Orderlines: Array[3]}`

in the array are 3 objects:

```
{"Klant":{},"Orderlines":[
{"id":"2793","number":1,"membershiptype":"New","lineid":"3521"},
{"id":"2802","number":1,"membershiptype":"New","lineid":"3522"},
{"id":"2803","number":1,"membershiptype":"New","lineid":"3523"}
]}
```

and after deleting a item: `Basket {Klant: Object, Orderlines: Object}`

and in the object are still 2 objects:

```
{"Klant":{},"Orderlines":{
"0":{"id":"2793","number":1,"membershiptype":"New","lineid":"3521"}
"2":{"id":"2803","number":1,"membershiptype":"New","lineid":"3523"}
}}
```

i tried splicing and deleting the array, but with the same result.
i want the result to be:

```
{"Klant":{},"Orderlines":[
{"id":"2793","number":1,"membershiptype":"New","lineid":"3521"},
{"id":"2803","number":1,"membershiptype":"New","lineid":"3523"}
]}
```

here is my code:

```
function Basket() {
  this.Klant = {};
  this.Orderlines = [];
  Basketdata = null;
  // check if we have storage and can use it.
  if (typeof (Storage) !== "undefined") {
        Basketdata = sessionStorage.getItem("Basket");
        total = sessionStorage.getItem("aantalitems");
        $('#aantalitems').html(total);

        console.log(Basketdata);
        if (Basketdata != null) {
              mybasket = JSON.parse(Basketdata);
              this.Orderlines = mybasket.Orderlines;
              this.Klant = mybasket.Klant;
        }
  }
  if (Basketdata == null) {
        Basketdata = {};
  }
  $('a.addcart').on('click', {this: this}, this.addArticle);
  $('a.remove_cart_item').on('click', {this: this}, this.deleteArticle);
  $('input.ChangeAmount').on('keyup change', {this: this}, this.changeAmount);

}

Basket.prototype = {
  constructor: Basket,

deleteArticle: function (event) {
        var knop = $(event.currentTarget);
        var mainartikel = $(knop).parents('tr.cart_item');
        var id = $(mainartikel).attr('id');
        var total = 0;
        for (var i in  event.data.this.Orderlines) {
              var line = event.data.this.Orderlines[i];
              if (line.lineid === id) {
                    console.log(event.data.this.Orderlines[i]);
                    console.log(i);
                    event.data.this.Orderlines[i].delete = 1;
              } else {
                    total += line.number;
              }
        }
        sessionStorage.setItem("aantalitems", total);
        $(mainartikel).fadeOut(function () {
              $(this).remove();
        });
        sessionStorage.setItem("Basket", JSON.stringify(event.data.this));
        event.data.this.sendToServer(event.data.this);



  },
 sendToServer: function (object) {
        $.ajax({
              type: "POST",
              url: '/shop?addtoorder=1',
              data: JSON.stringify(this),
              dataType: 'json',
              databasket: object
        }).done(function (data) {
              this.databasket.Orderlines = data.Orderlines;
              for (var i in  this.databasket.Orderlines) {
                    if (this.databasket.Orderlines[i].delete == 1) {
                        //here is the delete
                          //delete this.databasket.Orderlines[i];
                          this.databasket.Orderlines.splice(i,1);
                    }
                    if (this.databasket.Orderlines[i].update == 1) {
                          this.databasket.Orderlines[i].update = 0;
                          location.reload();
                    }
              }
              sessionStorage.setItem("Basket", JSON.stringify(this.databasket));
              $('#totalprice').html(data.total);
              if (this.databasket.Orderlines.length == 0) {
                    this.Orderlines = [];

                    $('div.content').html('\
<div style="float: left;"><b><a href="../../../shop"><img src="../../lib/items/Checkout/template/go-home-icon.png" width="32" height="32" alt="go-home-icon"  style="vertical-align: middle;"> Back to the shop</a></b></div>\n\
<br><br>No items in basket\n\
');
              }
        });
  }};
```

what i've tried so far:

under deleteArticle
i tried changing: `event.data.this.Orderlines[i].delete = 1;`

to: `delete event.data.this.Orderlines[i]`

which also ended up changing the array to a object

under sendToServer
i tried both

```
delete this.databasket.Orderlines[i];
this.databasket.Orderlines.splice(i,1);
```

which also ended up changing the array to a object

Comment: Can you create a jsfiddle to test it?

Comment: @nils i'll give it a try, might take some time tough

Comment: Deleting doesn't seem the be the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/Lfudroe4/
I think this has something to do with the `data` variable that comes from your JSON response. Also, why do you delete the orderline on the client side instead of on the server?

Comment: @nils that because its a sessionstorage which is saved on the client

Comment: I might be in the completely wrong part of the code in that case. I was talking about this:
```}).done(function (data) {
              this.databasket.Orderlines = data.Orderlines; ...``` In this part of the code, `this.databasket.Orderlines` is overwritten by data from the server. The sessionStorage part happens afterwards. So I was wondering: Why did you not delete these entries on the server and only return the entries that still exist?

Comment: @nils am i not doing that already? if i am doing `delete this.databasket.Orderlines[i]` which is just below that, and before the sessionstorage

Comment: Yes, my question is: Why are you deleting them in javascript at all? Why not delete them on the server in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
delete yourObj['Orderlines']
```

```js
var obj = {Basket: {Klant: Object, Orderlines: Array[0]}};
obj['Orderlines'] = [
{"id":"2793","number":1,"membershiptype":"New","lineid":"3521"},
{"id":"2802","number":1,"membershiptype":"New","lineid":"3522"},
{"id":"2803","number":1,"membershiptype":"New","lineid":"3523"}
];
document.write('After adding to obj[\'Orderlines\']: ' + obj['Orderlines'] + '<br/>');
delete obj['Orderlines'];
document.write('After deleting from obj[\'Orderlines\']: ' + obj['Orderlines']);
```